# Unsigned integer bit field shift yields signed integer

Tags: c, gcc, clang, bit-shift, bit-fields

Let consider the following program `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    unsigned int a:5;
};

int main () {
    unsigned int i;
    struct test t = {1};
    for (i = 0; i < t.a << 1; i++)
        printf("%u\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -Wsign-compare test.c` the following warning is produced (tested with gcc 4.8.1):

```
test.c:9:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (i = 0; i < t.a << 1; i++)
                   ^
```

`clang -Wsign-compare test.c` produces the following (tested with clang 3.2):

```
test.c:9:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    for (i = 0; i < t.a << 1; i++)
                ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Thus the right operand, a shifted unsigned bit field, becomes a signed int. This warning shows for any bit field value between 1 and 31 included. For higher values no warning is produced. This is weird.

This was tested with a bit field of type `unsigned short`, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long`. The latter do not show any warning for bit field values between 32 and 64 included.

When no shifting is done there is no warning, hence the bit field is unsigned as expected.

Why bit fields of size lower than 32 bits become signed when shifted? I assume this is not a bug since this is consistent with both `gcc` and `clang`. I must be missing some info about how bit fields (or shifting) work but what? How can shifting an unsigned value yield a signed value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integer promotions are applied to the operands of shift covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.7` *Bitwise shift operators* paragraph *3* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.[...]

and the integer promotion of a bit-field is covered in section `6.3.1.1` *Boolean, characters, and integers* paragraph *2* which says:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
>   be used:

and contains the following bullet:

> — **A bit-field** of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.

and then says:

> **If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;** otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are called the integer
>   promotions**.<sup>48)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

it was clarified in the [draft C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standard:

> If an int can represent all values of the original type **(as restricted by the width, for a bit-field)**, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So this is expected behavior.

Comment: And a 31 bit unsigned integer can be represented as an int and thus is promoted, but a 32 bit unsigned int cannot be promoted and is left as is. I didn't know about promotion. Thanks.

Comment: @bootleg If a 32 bit `unsigned int` can or cannot be promoted depends on the width of `unsigned int`.  Different results for 32 and 64-bit `unsigned`.