# warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, int, undefined-behavior, bit-shift, unsigned-char

I have the following piece of code:

```
long int compute_data_length(unsigned char* buf, int data_offset) {

long int len;

if(!buf)
    return -1;

switch(data_offset) {
    case 2: {
                len = (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
            }
            break;
    case 8: {
                len = (buf[2] << 56) |
                      (buf[3] << 48) |
                      (buf[4] << 40) |
                      (buf[5] << 32) |
                      (buf[6] << 24) |
                      (buf[7] << 16) |
                      (buf[8] <<  8) |
                      (buf[9]      );
            }
            break;
    default: len = -1; break;
}
return len;
}
```

When I compile, I get the following warning:

> math_fun.c:240:21: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
>                        len = (buf[2] << 56) |
>                        ^
>   math_fun.c:241:27: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
>                              (buf[3] << 48) |
>                              ^
>   math_fun.c:242:27: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
>                              (buf[4] << 40) |
>                              ^
>   math_fun.c:243:27: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
>                              (buf[5] << 32) |

How do I fix the warning?

Comment: How big is `long int`? Cast to the right type before doing the shifting.

Comment: -bash-4.1$ ./a.out 
size of long int 8 long long 8 unsigned long 8

Comment: Closely related to [Unsigned integer bit field shift yields signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152636/unsigned-integer-bit-field-shift-yields-signed-integer/22152886#22152886), on the fence whether it is a dup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: left shift count >= width of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201301/warning-left-shift-count-width-of-type)

Answer (score 5):

Integer promotions turn `buf[2] << 56` into `(int)buf[2] << 56` [Note 1], but it is entirely possible that `int` only has 32 bits and you need it to be an unsigned 64-bit type for the shift to be meaningful.

You're expecting `unsigned long` to be 64 bits, but it might not be. It would be better to include `<stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t`. In any event, you need to explicitly cast the left operands of thE left shift:

```
((uint64_t)buf[2] << 56) | ...
```

---

[Note 1]: It's theoretically possible for `unsigned char` to be as wide as an `int`, in which case the integer promotion would be to an `unsigned int`. But that only happens on unusual architectures.

Comment: A minor detail that doesn't really affect the quality of this answer, but `buf[2]` will be nearly always be promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for `unsigned char` to be as wide as `int` in C99.  The existence of `uint8_t` seems to imply that `unsigned char` is 8 bits wide, but `int` has to be more than that.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: C99 standard, 7.20.1.1 (*Exact-width integer types*), para 3, emphasis added: "**These types are optional.** However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names."

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to read warnings:

> math_fun.c:240:21: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default] len = (buf[2] << 56) | ^

That gives you all the info you need to comprehend your error and how to remedy it:

The type you shift is less than 56 bits long, so shifting 56 bits or more is **undefined behavior**.
Cast to an appropriately bigger type first.

I hope `long` fits the bill on your platform, because that's the type of the variable you later assign the result to. `int64_t` would be guaranteed to be big enough, *if it is provided*.

While you are at it, consider using only `unsigned` types there, overflow on `signed` types is undefined.